# Missing libraries in Host Integration Server 2016

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk, .net-assembly

We're in the process of upgrading from HIS 2009 to 2016, but it seems some of the libraries have changed and are no longer bundled with HIS (in the past, we would grab DLLs for reference from the System folder).

Specifically, the new constructor for `RuntimeCallContext` requires `HostIntegration.EventLogging.EventLogContainer`, but I can't find any DLL containing this class.

This is also true for the `IPrimitiveConverter` which is now of type `HostIntegration.Common.IPrimitiveConverter`.

As well as these two, the Event Log types `TIEventLogging`, `InternalTITracing` and `TITracing` also appear to be missing (possibly replaced by something in the `HostIntegration.EventLogging` namespace?).

Does anyone know where I could find DLLs for these types?  I have completed other necessary conversions (i.e. updating the solution from VS 2008 to 2015 and minor reference updates) but I'm really stuck on these classes.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the DLLs I needed were in Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL (didn't think to check there since 2009 has a copy in the HIS folder and some of them in the GAC list).

Still dealing with some type issues, but this immediate problem has been solved by referencing the DLLs from that location.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure HIS using configuration wizard to see if it helps, it did for us for some missing COM+ packages. Earlier these packages were part of MSI install but with 2016 they got installed after configuration. if it does not help contact your MS support to find out as there is not much help and documentation on it.

Comment: I had run the Configuration Wizard originally with Common Settings, Application Integration and Visual Studio Integration, but tried again including the other options (Network Integration, Data Integration, Session Integration, and Message Integration) but unfortunately no change.

Comment: Your best bet would be to contact MS support then,